# ¿como traer datos de una BD con un DataSet y mostrarlos en un reporte?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, devexpress

Estoy tratando de traer los datos de una BD en Postgresql con un DataSet para luego mostrarlos en un reporte pero no he podido.

Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
String sql;
        NpgsqlConnection cn;
        NpgsqlCommand cm;
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM facturacion,dtfactura ";
        cn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5433; User Id=postgres;Password=pasword;Database =tienda");
        cn.Open();
        cm = new NpgsqlCommand();
        cm.CommandText = sql;
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cm.Connection = cn;
        cm.Parameters.Add("factura", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
        cm.Parameters["factura"].Value = 1;
        da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cm);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Tu consulta es demasiado genérica, que has realizado para intentar mostrar ese Dataset en el reporte?, lo necesitas hacer con crystalreport, html, etc?

Comment: de manera general, lo que debes hacer es ejecutar el query, pasar ese query a un dataset y ese dataset mostarlo en una tabla del reporte etc, pero ahi depende que estes usando, reportviewer, crystal u algun otro

Comment: estoy usando DebExpres para hacer el reporte

Comment: porque defines un parametro que el SELECT no usa?

Comment: es que eso lo saque de un ejemplo que vi por Internet

Comment: siempre copias todo lo que esta en internet si entender que estas haciendo, asi esta claro que no va a funcionar

Comment: revisa ademas que el SELECT esta incorrecto, porque despues del FROM has escrito facturacion y con una coma dtfactura , eso ultimo despues de la coma no debe estar alli

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema se debe a que defines un parametro en el codigo que no usas, por eso debes de tener un fallo en la ejecucion

```
string connstring = "Server=localhost;Port=5433; User Id=postgres;Password=pasword;Database =tienda";
NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);

string sql = "SELECT * FROM facturacion";
NpgsqlCommand cm = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, cn);

NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cm);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

en el ejemplo simplifique algo el codigo para hacelro mas compacto con menos lineas

Valida que se este cargando los registros poniendo un breakpoint en el codigo he inspeccionando el dataset

Comment: que mas le debo agregar a el codigo?

Comment: si la consulta retorna datos y ejecuta son error imagino el siguiente paso sera asignar este al DataSource del componente devexpress